# Pixelating an image using Pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to pixelate an image using Pillow in Python. My program aims to take the average color across a group of pixels (50x50 in this case) and apply that to the group. However this only happens for the first 50x50 block and then the rest of the picture remains unpixelated. Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image

def pixelate(img):
    pixels = img.load()
    colors = []
    current_color = pixels[0,0]
    pix_size = 50

    for i in range(0, img.size[0], pix_size):
        for j in range(0, img.size[1], pix_size):
            red_avg = 0
            green_avg = 0
            blue_avg = 0
            current = pixels[i,j]
            for m in range(pix_size):
                for n in range(pix_size):
                    red_avg += pixels[m,n][0]
                    green_avg += pixels[m,n][1]
                    blue_avg += pixels[m,n][2]
            red_avg = red_avg // (pix_size * pix_size)
            green_avg = green_avg // (pix_size * pix_size)
            blue_avg = blue_avg // (pix_size * pix_size)
            for h in range(pix_size):
                for k in range(pix_size):
                    pixels[h,k] = (red_avg, green_avg, blue_avg)

    return img

img = Image.open('wallaby.jpg')
new = pixelate(img)
new.show()
```

And [here's the image I've been using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nolp4.jpg) (save as wallaby.jpg if you don't want to edit the code):

Am I missing something conceptually or just making a silly mistake in my code?

I should also note that this is part of an assignment and am not looking for a complete solution, just perhaps a reason why my method isn't currently working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The easy/normal way to do this is to resize the image down to, say, 10% of its original size then scale it back up to its original size using nearest neighbour interpolation.

Comment: Take a look at your offsets - you barely use i,j, which define your "sliding window" so to speak. Instead, you always only work on the upper left corner. You need to adapt your pixel access accordingly.

Comment: @deets I see what you mean! This helped me realize that I wasn't offsetting my m,n and h,k variables by i and j, respectively. Thanks so much!